# Nature of the electric field of a photon

Tags: photons, electric-fields

I only have a basic, mostly classical understanding of physics and am just starting to learn about photons. Am I correct in saying that, as a photon moves through space, the strength of its electric field varies? If I am correct, what is the qualitative nature of this field? Is it positive (would repel a nearby proton it was passing by) or negative (would attract a nearby proton it was passing by)? Does it switch between positive and negative? Or would it have no effect on a proton it was passing by (the field is neither positive or negative)? If the field is neither, how is it even possible for an electric field to exist without being positive or negative? What would such a field even mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the relation between electromagnetic wave and photon?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90646/)

Comment: Just to confuse things even more, a photon does not carry electric charge.   https://van.physics.illinois.edu/qa/listing.php?id=2348